# Extract words between parentheses

Tags: java, regex, string, extract

I am trying to solve a fairly easy problem but can't quite figure out how to use regexs properly. I want to extract any words from a text file between (parentheses). This was the sort of attempt I have going. Any shove in the right direction would be appreciated!!

```
public class Reader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");

        try{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test2.txt"));

            while(bufferedReader.readLine()!=null)
            {
                String parseMe = bufferedReader.readLine();

                Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(parseMe);

                while (regexMatcher.find()) 
                {
                    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
                } 
            }
            System.out.println(matchList);
        }catch(IOException e){};
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of the above code?

Comment: What's the problem? Also, at least print the stack trace in your catch block: swallowing like that makes debugging hard for yourself.

Comment: Are you talking about braces '{}'or parenthesis '()'?

Comment: When I run this code I get an empty list. Also I was trying to extract words within ( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex string should (at least) be `"[({\\[].*?[\\]})]"` The outer square brackets are regex syntax -- you are defining a *character class* to look for. It's not perfect and a completely correct solution is impossible in Java regex (you can't account for nested brackets). But there's a start :) BTW you may find it useful to experiment with the regex using Eclipse Find. It's even got a great content assist.

Comment: How would I go about only capturing words in ( ) parentheses ??

Comment: Extracting a sequence of strings is another matter -- it will have to be another regex executed upon the strings returned from the one you have now. That inner regex would be `"\\w+"`

Answer (score 3):

You are skipping every second line.  Read each line once.

```
String parseMe;
while((parseMe = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(parseMe);
```

I would remove the try/catch block as it doesn't do anything useful.  You can have main `thorws IOException` instead.